# Java IO: Redirect Large Byte Stream (> 400MB) from InputStream to ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, tomcat, httpurlconnection, java-io, http-get

Application Server: Apache Tomcat 8.0

I have a doGet method that allows the user to download files. The files to be downloaded do not reside on server, but instead we read the files from an URL (get method) through an input stream and then redirect the bytes to the servlet output stream.

In the doGet method:

1. Use http client to open a connection with the url which contains the file
2. Open an input stream from the connection
3. Use IOUtils.copyLarge to redirect the InputStream (from the url connection) to the ServletOutputStream.

The above works fine for small files. But if the file to be downloaded is sufficiently large (often over 400MB), we start seeing the following exception:

```html
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1793)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
```

What is the most reliable way of redirecting byte stream from an url to the user without storing the file on the server?

Comment: Are you the one downloading the large file, or is it some unknown user of the app? Because he/she could just have aborted the download.

Comment: The client is closing the connection prematurely. Post the client code.

Comment: @JBNizet, the client is the one downloading the file through an endpoint I provide them. Process: the client sends a get request to my server to get the file -> my server open an url connection to get an input stream from another third party endpoint -> my sever redirects the input stream into the servlet output stream for the user.

Comment: @EJP, we are simply proving the user an url (an endpoint) to download the file. Our user mostly use chrome or firefox to download the file, which I believe is equivalent to sending a get request to my server. I don't have the error log from the user. It is reported that they see the download hanging there for a while and then it's terminated. At the end, they are getting a corrupted file.

Comment: So they aborted the transfer, and this is how it gets detected.